# Half of page not displaying on mobile devices

Tags: html, css

I have the [following](http://www.inspuratesystems.com/nayajeevan/?page_id=126) page in which the website's contents on the right get hidden.

Please guide me why is it happening and how to solve it. Thank you.

```
<div id="responsivearea" style="margin-top: -23px; padding-top: 90px;">
<div class="img-center"><img class="wp-image-2520 alignleft" style="margin-right: 180px;" src="http://www.inspuratesystems.com/nayajeevan/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/Meet-rabia.png" alt="good employer" width="190" height="100" /><a href="http://asiasociety.org/video/asher-hasan-spark-extinguished" target="_blank"><img id="AshersStory" class="wp-image-2521 alignleft" style="margin-right: 80px;" src="http://www.inspuratesystems.com/nayajeevan/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/Ashers-story-circle.png" alt="gift of health" width="190" height="188" /></a></div>
</div>
</div>
<p style="float: left; margin-left: 48px; font-size: 25px;">MEET RABIA</p>
<p style="float: right; margin-top: -79px; margin-right: 100px; font-size: 25px;">ASHER'S STORY</p>

<div>
<p style="float: left; margin-left: 26px; font-size: 15px; width: 200px;">Everything is hand coded and every little detail is given attention. We will go the extra mile to make your product perfect.
<a style="color: #fd685b;" href="#"><strong>LEARN MORE</strong></a></p>
<p style="float: right; margin-top: -183px; margin-right: 107px; font-size: 15px; width: 180px;">Asher was born and raised in England until the age of eleven. At that time, his father’s untimely death prompted
<a style="color: #fd685b;"http://www.inspuratesystems.com/nayajeevan/?p=3202"><strong>LEARN MORE</strong></a></p>
```

Comment: I like the design. It's really nice. The answers below should help solve your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

view-source:http://www.inspuratesystems.com/nayajeevan/?page_id=126 line 178 - you have strict value of width to `700px`.

Try use `max-width` for example.

Also line 242 `(600px width)`

Answer (score 2):

U are giving everything a width in `px`. Which is not good for mobile devices as they have different sizes.
You should us `%` for width so it takes a part of the screen rather then an exact amount of pixels.

At the moment at multiple places in your website the amount of pixels is larger then the screen which is why you can't see the elements.